# Why Scanner Class does not use the concept of overloading just like println method

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

As like in println method we can use the same method to enter different types of data without any issues. So, likewise why cant we use scanner on the same basis unlike we have to specify each time the type of values we have to enter.
As we use different methods to enter different datatypes form the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not support return-type-based method overloading.

While this is legal:

```
class Something {
    void act(int i) { /* ... */ }
    void act(double d) { /* ... */ }
}
```

This is illegal:

```
class Something {
    int act() { /* ... */ }
    double act() { /* ... */ }
}
```